# PDF file could not be accessed in samsung j6 but can accessible in other android phones

Tags: java, android, pdf, samsung-galaxy

I am receving this **error:  The file could not be accessed check your connection or make the filename shorter**  when trying to open a **PDF** file with **Samsung j6**, but I am able to open the same file with other **android** phone like Tecno.

Below is the code that I am using to open a PDF file.

```
        File d = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        File pdfFile = new File(d, examID+".pdf");

        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", pdfFile);

        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
            startActivity(pdfIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(DocExamView.this, "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Just because the `OS` is the same it doesn't mean that their `OEM` (Original Equipment Manufacturer) will have the same softwares. If you install a `PDF` reader app probably it will work.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian yes the PDF reader is installed.

Comment: I am also gettign the same error in samsung alone, I have installed PDF Reader apps also , any suggestion why I am getting this error ??